# "SwiftChart" pod library has an error in Chart.swift file

Tags: swiftcharts

[image]There is an error in Chart.swift file which is part of the "SwiftChart" pod library. It says "kCALineJoinBevel" has been renamed to "CAShapeLayerLineJoin.bevel".

Could you please correct this?

Comment: show some code pls

Comment: Sorry..posted the screenshot of the error and the code.

Comment: Just as a heads up, people prefer pasted code here. Your error seems to be cause by the SwiftChart framework being developed in older swift/xcode version, so check if it was updated or just try to modify the source code to say `CAShapeLayerLineJoin.bevel`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have tried checking for an update, seems that they have but I don't get that update when I do "pod update".
I have changed at my end but this goes to Jenkins, and jenkins would do a fresh install of the pods everytime. So, jenkins build is crashing because of this error.

Comment: you can try specifying an exact version of the pod